# Residual Plot Analysis

Tags: statistics, regression

I'm working on building a regression model for a large set of data (n>54000). Clearly a ton of assumptions are being violated that I have to try and adjust for. I'm all for transformations of data and have looked into robust regressions, but I'm completely clueless as to how I would adjust for a residual plot that looks like this:

[image]

Any suggestions on how this could be handled?

Comment: What is the motivation for you regression and the equation you are trying to run?

Comment: This residual plot makes it look like it's more or less normally distributed around $0$, relatively independent of whatever your $x$ axis stands for. I recommend a frequency plot instead, seeing if the data is in fact normally distributed.